# SVG CSS transition transform flickering in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a button that has an icon, which is inline svg elements. When I click the icon, there's three transformations that's applied by css.

1. The white svg circle translates to main black circle to overlap it.
2. The g container that holds both circles, is scaled up.
3. The g container that holds both circles, is rotated 30 degrees.

In Firefox there's a flicker once the circles overlap at end of transition.

It's difficult to debug because when I open the firefox devtools, the flickering rarely happens.

```js
const btnToggle = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const moonShadow = document.querySelector(".moon-shadow");
const sunAndMoon = document.querySelector(".sun-and-moon");

let toggle = true;
btnToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (toggle) {
    moonShadow.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
    sunAndMoon.style.transform = "scale(1.5) rotate(30deg)";
  } else {
    moonShadow.style.transform = "translateX(-15px)";
    sunAndMoon.style.transform = "scale(1) rotate(0deg)";
  }
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-toggle {
  border: 0;
  background: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* svg classes */
.sun-and-moon {
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}
.moon-shadow {
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 550ms;
}
```

```html
<main>
   <p>Click icon</p>
    <button class="btn-toggle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="84.0661" height="84.0661" viewBox="0 0 22.2425 22.2425">
        <g class="sun-and-moon">
          <circle class="sun" r="4.4093" cy="11.1212" cx="11.1212" fill="currentColor" />
          <circle class="moon-shadow" style="transform: translateX(-15px);" r="4.4093" cy="11.1212" cx="7.5566"
            fill="#fff" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </main>
```

Comment: It's very noticeable in Firefox 76 & 77.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tweaked your code a little to make it work, also removed the inline CSS set by JavaScript since it is not something I would recommend if it isn't necessary. ;)

What actually 'solves' the problem is:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

**Code example**
[https://jsfiddle.net/*Dave*/k0q4m5jr/](https://jsfiddle.net/_Dave_/k0q4m5jr/)

**HTML**

```
<main>
   <p>Click icon</p>
    <button class="btn-toggle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="84.0661" height="84.0661" viewBox="0 0 22.2425 22.2425">
        <g class="sun-and-moon">
          <circle class="sun" r="4.4093" cy="11.1212" cx="11.1212" fill="currentColor" />
          <circle class="moon-shadow" r="4.4093" cy="11.1212" cx="7.5566"
            fill="#fff" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </main>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-toggle {
  border: 0;
  background: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* svg classes */
.sun-and-moon {
  backface-visibility: hidden; /* Prevents flickering */
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 450ms;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);

   /* Added, to prevent inline CSS when not needed. */
  .is-active & {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(30deg);
  }
}
.moon-shadow {
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* Prevents flickering */
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-15px);
  transition: transform 550ms;

   /* Added, to prevent inline CSS when not needed. */
  .is-active & {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const btnToggle = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const moonShadow = document.querySelector(".moon-shadow");
const sunAndMoon = document.querySelector(".sun-and-moon");
const activeClass = 'is-active';

btnToggle.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let isActive = event.currentTarget.classList.contains(activeClass);

  if (!isActive) {
    btnToggle.classList.add(activeClass);
  } else {
    btnToggle.classList.remove(activeClass);
  }
});
```

Comment: It fixes it but only when parts of svg are transitioned. When whole block containing svg is transitioned (eg. `transform: scale(1, 0)` to `transform: scale(1, 1)`), then svg still flickers and seems to have some rendering issues in Firefox.